# Conserved acetylation sites in a given protein

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins

I want to identify potential conserved Acetylation sites in protein X. As it is known, acetylation happens in Lysines (K), thereby I would like to identify conserved K residues for protein X during evolution. Eventually I would use different Acetylation site prediction tools to further filter the results, but initially I need the other data, does anyone know a user friendly but trust worthy bioinformatic tool to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NCBI subpage [HomoloGene](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/homologene/1648)

Halfway down page on left you can choose to show Multiple Alignment as seen in this screenshot.

[image: Pic]

I think you will then see what you are looking for as in this screenshot:

[image]